# Android Studio Rendering Problems with an Android version lower than 6

Tags: android, android-studio

I start New Android project "Blank Activity" in Android Studio with Android 4.0

[image]

but I noticed that for rendering used API 23 (Android 6.0)

[image]

and if I click to use Android 4.0 (4.4W.2, 4.4.2, 4.3.1, 4.2.2, 4.0.3), i receive the following error:

```
Rendering Problems
The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
    - PorterDuff Color Filter are not supported. (Igrone for this session)
```

[image]

Tell me please how to fix this problem and why it happens.
Or it is quite normal that for rendering the project that uses the Android 4.0 uses Android 6.0 ?

I use Android Studio 1.5.1 141.2456560 and Java SE Development Kit 1.7.0_79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer to this question

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sxo5zMcOCXM

The application for a specific API will have forward compatibility with future releases. Platform SDK uses the target value if the near future platforms will be expected a significant change in behavior. This ensures that the application will not break when you upgrade a user's phone.

It turns out that it does not matter as what API to use for rendering the project. If you created your project for the minimum Android 4.0 platform and rendering in Android Studio using Android 6.0 then it is quite normal.